Is it possible in sveltekit to create a folder based route with two dynamic slugs in a row?
I'm working on doing a 1:1 port of an existing svelte app that I created back around 2019 to svelte kit.
I currently have a route defined like this where there are two slugs back to back
/l/:token/:secret
Is there a way to express this in the folder based routing provided by sveltekit?

Note that I understand it would be easy ( and sensible ) to change this to something else, but this is an existing and actively used application and making a breaking change to this url structure would adversely affect users, so I plan to keep it as it.

Thanks!

Just make one folder under another

You can have as many nested parameters as you want, as long as the routes do not become ambiguous. So this should just be:
src/routes/l/[token]/[secret]/+page.svelte

